# Comparing content of a textfile with Filenames in the order to rename / filter not wanted phrases/keywords

Tags: python-3.x

I would like implement txt file with keywords to use instead of a single keyword (list = "Red")

```
import os

path = r"C:\..."
list = "Red"
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if list in filename:
        filepath = os.path.join(path, filename)
        newfilepath = os.path.join(pfad, filename.replace(list, ""))
        os.rename(filepath, newfilepath)
```

Pls help.

Comment: it should be `if filename in list:`

Comment: Yes that removes the error but it does nothing after change...
Iam not sure if this change doesnt change the way it works bc it should proof if the filename contains those specific keywords and replace them with "" null

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: for example i have serveral files with diffrent names. They contain specific phrases what are not wanted. This script remove those. But this works only with 1 keyword currently (list = "Red").
I want to change "list =" to a textfile so the procedure below will be executet for all words/phrases from the txt file and its containing keywords.

Comment: Someone any idea how to adapt the code to use a textfile with keywords instead of a single keyword?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script would read the file with `blacklist` words and replace them in `filename` string. I have just worked with your code. Let me know if I have misunderstood something.

```
import os


def read_text_file(txt_file_path): #reads data from text file
    blacklist = []
    with open(txt_file_path, "r") as f:
      lines = f.readlines()
    for elem in lines:
        blacklist.append(elem.strip())
    return blacklist

def replace_blacklist(filepath):   #replaces blacklisted words in filepath
    global BLACKLIST
    for elem in BLACKLIST:
        filepath = filepath.replace(elem,"")
    return filepath


PATH  = r"C:\..."   #your root dir path
BLACKLIST = read_text_file("data.txt") #data containing blacklisted words, please separate them line by line

for file in os.listdir(PATH):
    if any(x in file for x in BLACKLIST):
        filepath = os.path.join(PATH,file)
        newfilepath = replace_blacklist(filepath)
        os.rename(filepath,newfilepath)
```

My  `data.txt` looked like this:

```
Black
Grey
Red
Green
Blue
Yellow
```

Comment: You did great job! Thank you alot! This is exactly what i want / meant. Thx 1000 times :)